# Unable to ping IP address between two locations

Tags: ip-address, isp, ping

I have two locations office and home. From home I am unable to access my mail server and from the office I am unable to access my personal web server.

Now, these two locations are about 100 yards away and share the same connection from the ISP. It's payed for on the same account. Also they both have different static public IP addresses. office is `216.248.94.xxx` and home is `216.51.158.xxx`. I cannot ping each address from each location.

Comment: Two Windows machines? It's most likely windows security settings. Are you trying to share files?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure ICMP ping is enabled? (Can you ping those addresses from another network?)

You might have that blocked in either the firewall or the computer itself, if it runs on a dedicated IP address.

Comment: Yep it is enabled. I can ping it from another network and access it from another network. Only when I am on these two networks that I cannot access each other.

Comment: Can ICMP be blocked by routers between your networks and enabled on the machines?

Comment: @Anagio - Yes, but then they would only work directly to the machine that has them enabled. You can block them on your WAN but all machines still allow it, so pinging any machine on the LAN network would still work.

Comment: I would say at this point it's time to talk to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping these IP's from a public ping server like http://www.adminkit.net/ping.aspx and if the result is time out try to check firewall configuration on both machines to enable ICMP protocol.